# When do RAM modules generate heat?

Tags: memory, cooling, overheating

I have two questions regarding heat generation of RAM modules.

1. Do RAM modules generate more heat when there are (many) reads and writes to them as opposed to when they are sitting idle?
2. Do RAM modules generate heat when the computer/laptop is in the suspended state? If yes, at least do they generate less heat as opposed to when the computer is on?

Comment: you need to acknowledge the answer here. I went back and checked: Average temperature around the keyboard (heat rises) on two laptop is 24 degrees, disk drive (X230) 25 degrees; fan output (GPU, CPU) 26 degrees, Desktop twin 2 TB SSD drives (memory) 24 degrees.  Memory does not heat up any computer; CPU, GPU and Disk do that.

Comment: This is a very nice academical question, might be interesting for people who are designing some complex systems that use lots of RAM modules (like tens or hundreds of modules). Shame there is no really good qualified answer for it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Short answer is yes, more activity, more heat. Depending on the suspended state, much less or none. If the RAM is still "on" much less, if it's hibernation none (as the RAM is dumped onto the hard disc and powered off.

Ram is not usually the major contributor of heat in a PC though. Other processors usually cause more. I.e. CPU, mainboard bridge processors and GPUs. The PSU can get warm too.  Some Hard discs get warm too.

Comment: Ram does heat up, depending on the PC build, depends how much. It's just not going to be the thing that causes excess heat in a PC.  The question was does RAM generate more heat under a load, the answer is 100% YES. The question was not can RAM cause PC overheating, which is not likely, your other components will do that first.  Which is what I said, so I have no idea why I got a down vote for answering a question, and then clarifying relevance.

Answer (score 0):

Memory modules do not generate significant heat and certainly no appreciable heat when suspended.

CPU chips, GPU chips, Power Supply if built in (not laptop) and disk drives generate heat.

But (using an IR thermometer from time to time) not memory.